# Adding a admin-to-test-user comment box in head section of wordpress

Tags: wordpress-theming, wordpress

Our content admin has non-sensitive info to post on certain web pages for certain users in our company. Based on how everything works in our company and our Wordpress site, we would like to add a head section based comment section for the admin. Then the select users that need to see this information can just view the page source. It would be gibberish to everyone else, so if others stumbled upon it, it wouldn't be a concern.

I am a php and mysql beginner which is why I'm asking this question. I set up a test WordPress environment, but I need a direction to go into for adding the head comment section into the individual Pages edit/publishing area. Can anyone provide this information for me, possibly a link or some code for me to start researching.

Thank in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Custom fields did it! I put this in the header section:

```
/** <?php if(get_post_meta($post->ID, "adminote", true) != '') echo get_post_meta($post->ID, "adminote", true); else echo ('No Notes');?> */
```

Then in the custom fields of each page I added the name 'adminnote' and the value (note) to follow.